# MySql Query Optimisation, replacing not in subquery with join

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query that I feel is very bulky and can do with optimisation. First thing would obviously be replacing not in subquery with join but it affects the sub-sub query that I have. I'd appreciate suggestions/workaround on it.

This is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM lastweeksales
WHERE productID =  1234
AND retailer NOT 
IN (
    SELECT retailer
    FROM sales
    WHERE productID
    IN (
        SELECT productID
        FROM products
        WHERE publisher = 123
    )
    AND DATE =  date(now())
)
```

Basically, I want to get rows from lastweek's sales on a product where retailers are not present that did sales today but sales should only be on products by a certain publisher.

:S:S:S

Comment: try not to use `NOT IN` or `IN` because every row in lastweeksales will project the subtable which has poor performance. Try to use join to get the data you want

Comment: @Neo Isn't it exactly what he is asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group together 2 inner subqueries easily via `INNER JOIN`. For the outer one you should use `LEFT OUTER` join and then filter on `retailer IS NULL`, like this:

```sql
SELECT lws.*
  FROM lastweeksales lws
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.retailer 
               FROM sales s
               JOIN products p USING (productID)
              WHERE p.publisher = 123
                AND s.date = date(now())) AS r
         ON lws.retailer = r.retailer
 WHERE r.retailer IS NULL;
```